# when using docker compose 3.8 getting 'version is unsupported' error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use the latest docker compose version 3.8 but I keep getting "Version in ".\docker-compose.yml" is unsupported." error.

I'm using the latest version of Docker engine, 19.03.8 and Docker desktop, 2.2.0.5.

EDIT:
Here is my docker compose version: docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  portal:
    image: portal-dev
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "4200:4200"
    container_name: portal
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER: 0
```

My docker compose file works using version 3.7. I can't figure out why it doesn't work using version 3.8. Can anyone help?

Comment: could you add output of `docker-compose version` to your question ?

Comment: @invad0r I added my version of docker-compose.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The 3.8 compose version was added in docker-compose 1.25.5 (ref: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.5 )

Docker Desktop 2.3 include the new version of compose but it's on the edge channel for now.

If you can/doesn't want to use the Edge Channel, you can download the latest version of docker-compose manually on the github release page https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Comment: Oh that's why. Thanks. The Docker website is misleading showing an example with 3.8 thinking its the current version when it really isn't.

Comment: I wonder why by default an outdated version is installed. That seems to be a trend.

Answer (score 12):

Follow the below steps to resolve the issue:

- Uninstall docker-compose (if installed)

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove docker-compose -y
  ```
- Get latest binary version of docker-compose from [github releases](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/)

  ```
  curl -O -J -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.11.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
  ```
- Make the binary executable.

```
chmod +x docker-compose-linux-x86_64
```

- Add this to binary look up location.

```
sudo cp ./docker-compose-linux-x86_64 /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

- check version

```
docker-compose version
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i solved via replace the version to 3.3 as the error log shows.

my docker compose is located at: /usr/bin/docker-compose

and its version is: docker-compose version 1.20.0, build xxxxxx

I totally agree the docker official website is misleading with the incorrect matched version with 3.9 for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I lost the customal location settings in the first place, I configure the location like this and it works:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "created_on": "2023-11-04 18:48:54",
  "modified_on": "2023-11-04 20:52:05",
  "owner_user_id": 1,
  "domain_names": [
    "likegiver.com"
  ],
  "forward_host": "8.219.255.71",
  "forward_port": 81,
  "access_list_id": 0,
  "certificate_id": 7,
  "ssl_forced": true,
  "caching_enabled": false,
  "block_exploits": false,
  "advanced_config": "",
  "meta": {
    "letsencrypt_agree": false,
    "dns_challenge": false
  },
  "allow_websocket_upgrade": true,
  "http2_support": false,
  "forward_scheme": "http",
  "enabled": 1,
  "locations": [
    {
      "path": "/game",
      "advanced_config": "",
      "forward_scheme": "http",
      "forward_host": "8.219.255.71/game",
      "forward_port": 8000
    }
  ],
  "hsts_enabled": false,
  "hsts_subdomains": false
}
```

I use the nginx as a reverse proxy so that I don't need to use http://likegiver.com:8000/game to visit my website. I can use https://likegiver.com/game instead.